# ESP8266 not connection to socket.io server Nodejs deployed on render

Tags: node.js, websocket, esp8266, arduino-ide

but the esp still connect and disconnect  , the server is https , i tried to use insecure socket connection but the compiler gives error , im using webSockets library on arduino and tried to search on google for similar problem but none of them worked for me

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>

const char* ssid = "your_wifi_ssid";
const char* password = "your_wifi_password";
const char* serverAddress = "your_server_address";
const int serverPort = 3000;

WebSocketsClient webSocket;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  webSocket.begin(serverAddress, serverPort, "/");
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);

  while (!webSocket.isConnected()) {
    webSocket.loop();
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WebSocket...");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WebSocket");
}

void loop() {
  webSocket.loop();
}

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t* payload, size_t length) {
  switch (type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.println("WebSocket disconnected");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      Serial.println("WebSocket connected");
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT: {
      String message = String((char*)payload);
      int brightness = message.toInt();
      analogWrite(D1, brightness);
      Serial.print("Brightness updated: ");
      Serial.println(brightness);
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

and i tried to change some cors settings

```
  cors: {
   origin: "*",
   methods: ["GET", "POST"],
   transports: ["websocket", "polling"],
   credentials: true,
  },
   allowEIO3: true,
  }
```

and this is my nodejs server

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5173'
}));
const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
   origin: "*",
   methods: ["GET", "POST"],
   transports: ["websocket", "polling"],
   credentials: true,
  },
   allowEIO3: true,
  });

let brightness = 0;
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New WebSocket connection');
  socket.emit('brightness', brightness);
  socket.on('brightness', (newBrightness) => {
    brightness = newBrightness;
    console.log('Brightness updated:', brightness);
    io.emit('brightness', brightness);
  });
});
```

EDIT:
now im able to connect to server but it directly disconnect , and on the server log it seems to connect here is the code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <Hash.h>

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
WebSocketsClient webSocket;

#define USE_SERIAL Serial1

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length) {
  switch (type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.println("[WSc] Disconnected!");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      {
        Serial.println("[WSc] Connected to url: " + String((char *)payload));

        // send message to server when Connected
        webSocket.sendTXT("Connected");
      }
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      Serial.println("[WSc] get text: " + String((char *)payload));

      // send message to server
      // webSocket.sendTXT("message here");
      break;
    case WStype_BIN:
      Serial.println("[WSc] get binary length: " + String(length));
      hexdump(payload, length);

      // send data to server
      // webSocket.sendBIN(payload, length);
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("starting");

  for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }

  WiFiMulti.addAP("ssid","passpass");

  while (WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("not connected");
    delay(100);
  }

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connected to the internet.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Not connected to the internet.");
  }

  webSocket.beginSocketIOSSL("url",443,"/socket.io/?EIO=3","arduino");
 

  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}

void loop() {
  webSocket.loop();
}
```